React Native Expo issue: the android App builded with EAS doesn't make the HTTPS request
I Developed an app with react native, using expo managed. I use a private server (own creation) to access the data, using HTTPS requests (with all the SSL certificates). On develepment, the requests are done succesfully, the app is able to conect de API in both Android and iOs, but when I build the Android app for production with eas and install the app in a device, the app isnt able to connect the API. I tried a lot of possible solutions, but i didnt find it yet. Could anyone give me help for this issue please? im new in the developing of mobile apps and Expo. here I show my app.json file
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "---",
    "slug": "-----",
    "version": "1.0.6",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/CFL.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "permissions": [
      "CAMERA",
      "MEDIA_LIBRARY",
      "INTERNET"
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/CFT.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#69C8FF"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/CFL.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "-----"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "------"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "usesCleartextTraffic": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}


I tried using "usesCleartextTraffic": true, but nothing happens. and giving internet permissions in the app.json. also i tried cleaning the cache before build the app with eas
